Positional embedding with device inconsistency error
I'm writing an attention block with Rotary Positional Embedding (RoPE). The following two pieces of code look basically the same to me in terms of the result of the "forward" function. (Logically, the first one additionally stores the rotary_embed as a member variable.) However, the latter will result in an error: "Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!" Why? Is there anything common about device that I should be aware of when adding positional embeddings?
The first:
# self attention block
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, max_len=11, rope=False):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.rope = rope
        if self.rope:
            self.rotary_emb = RotaryEmbedding(dim = self.embed_dim)
        self.c_attn = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim*3)
        self.register_buffer('mask', torch.tril(torch.ones(max_len, max_len)))
    def forward(self, x):  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)
        T = x.size(1)
        q, k, v = self.c_attn(x).chunk(3, dim=-1)
        if self.rope:
            q = self.rotary_emb.rotate_queries_or_keys(q)
            k = self.rotary_emb.rotate_queries_or_keys(k)
        y = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, is_causal=True)
        return y  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)

The second:
# self attention block
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, max_len=11, rope=False):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.rope = rope
        self.c_attn = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim*3)
        self.register_buffer('mask', torch.tril(torch.ones(max_len, max_len)))
    def forward(self, x):  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)
        T = x.size(1)
        q, k, v = self.c_attn(x).chunk(3, dim=-1)
        if self.rope:
            rope_emb = RotaryEmbedding(dim=self.embed_dim)
            q, k = rope_emb.rotate_queries_or_keys(q), rope_emb.rotate_queries_or_keys(k)
            print(q.shape, k.shape, v.shape)
        y = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, is_causal=True)
        return y  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)

The error of the second:
    <ipython-input-32-76e984ea5eb9> in forward(self, x)
     17         if self.rope:
     18             self.rotary_emb = RotaryEmbedding(dim = self.embed_dim)
---> 19             q = self.rotary_emb.rotate_queries_or_keys(q)
     20             k = self.rotary_emb.rotate_queries_or_keys(k)
     21             # print(q.shape, k.shape, v.shape)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rotary_embedding_torch/rotary_embedding_torch.py in rotate_queries_or_keys(self, t, seq_dim, offset, scale)
    181         seq = self.get_seq_pos(seq_len, device = device, dtype = dtype, offset = offset)
    182 
--> 183         freqs = self.forward(seq, seq_len = seq_len, offset = offset)
    184 
    185         if seq_dim == -3:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/amp/autocast_mode.py in decorate_autocast(*args, **kwargs)
     42     def decorate_autocast(*args, **kwargs):
     43         with autocast_instance:
---> 44             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     45 
     46     decorate_autocast.__script_unsupported = "@autocast() decorator is not supported in script mode"  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rotary_embedding_torch/rotary_embedding_torch.py in forward(self, t, seq_len, offset)
    311         freqs = self.freqs
    312 
--> 313         freqs = einsum('..., f -> ... f', t.type(freqs.dtype), freqs)
    314         freqs = repeat(freqs, '... n -> ... (n r)', r = 2)
    315 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/functional.py in einsum(*args)
    400         # the path for contracting 0 or 1 time(s) is already optimized
    401         # or the user has disabled using opt_einsum
--> 402         return _VF.einsum(equation, operands)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    403 
    404     path = None

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!

